# Admanager unfilled impression revenue problem

Tags: google-chrome, google-ad-manager, adx, revenue, ad-management

My Ad Manager was approved by a third-party company. I set up ads using Ad Exchange tags in the Ad Manager account and placed them on the website. All ads are displaying perfectly fine, but revenue and impressions are showing in the Non-programmatic channel, and it only shows as unfilled. I contacted the parent company, but they said there is no problem.

However, when I asked in some Facebook groups, they mentioned that we don't get paid for revenue from the non-programmatic channel and unfilled impressions.

Answer (score 0):

Since third party provided the tags and you implemented inside the GAM as a line item, All impressions will be counted against Non-programmatic channel.

They didn't gave you Adx child account they gave another MCM type called MCM MI which allow third party to generate the code and send to the publisher.
Third party is the one where they will be see every impressions against programmatic channel.

Thanks,
AdTagMacros